# Paste Values to New Sheet given row/column number in cells

Tags: vba, loops, copy, mapping, paste

I am attempting to create a loop that will paste values from the left (see picture below) into another workbook using the locations on the right (using "Today Column"). I have a whole sheet with blocks of values like shown in the picture. Any thoughts are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Windows("Book1.xlsm").Activate
    Range("G6:G10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Book2.xlsx").Activate
    Range("FC8").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```

[image: Paste values from the left into new workbook using locations on the right]

Comment: Are you copying from a specific sheet in Book1 and to a specific sheet in Book2?  Would help to include the column and row headers in your screenshot.

Comment: No need for copy paste, you can directly assign the values. No need for `Select` either, that just makes things jittery, slow and unreliable. You're missing the worksheets as well, currently you're relying on `ActiveSheet`. Here's how to do it as a 1-liner. 
`Application.Workbooks( "Book2.xlsx").Worksheets( "SHEETNAME").Range( "FC8:FC10").Value = Application.Workbooks( "Book1.xlsm").Worksheets( "SHEETNAME").Range( "G6:G10").Value`

Comment: That 1-liner is how to copy values between two workbooks given that you already know the source range and destination range. But if you don't know those ranges, you have to find them first. And you'll have to add more detail to this post for me to give any advice on that. For example, what exactly are you trying to copy? Are there conditions? What is the destination range?

Comment: @TimWilliams - Yes, for example: I am wanting to paste from Book1 Sheet1 the first red value (null in the photo) to the location mapped out in the same row to the right (Row 8, Column 219) of Book2 Sheet1. Then, I would like to go down the list pasting each to the respective locations on the right.

Comment: @Toddleson - Thanks for your thoughts! I hadn't thought of directly assigning values. My only issue now is pasting from Book1 Sheet1 to Book2 Sheet1 the values in red and green, to the cell location listed in the same row of the screenshot. The destination range could change as updates are made to the file, so I am looking to use the mapped locations in the screenshot.

Comment: If you loop though the column, you can go row by row and reference the values on the sheet as you go. So you could take the value, take the row number from the other cell and then use the row number in the address so you know where to put the value. There are many tutorials on how to write loops out there and plenty of example projects that you can copy.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to get this to do what you want with the appropriate adjustments:

```vb
Private Sub Tester()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet, c As Range, rw As Long, col As Long
    
    'Use `ThisWorkbook` if the workbook is where the macro is running
    Set wsSrc = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("data")         'or whatever
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Book2.xlsm").Worksheets("other sheet") 'or whatever
    
    For Each c In wsSrc.Range("G6:G10").Cells
        rw = c.Offset(0, 2).Value   'row number to copy to
        col = c.Offset(0, 4).Value  'column number to copy to
        If rw > 0 And col > 0 Then wsDest.Cells(rw, col).Value = c.Value
    Next c
End Sub
```